# Why does jQuery .on( 'click', foo ) run the function on page load and not on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a simple example of what i'm running into.

All I want to do is add an event handler for the function Foo to link1 so that when link1 is clicked it will run Foo.

But what is happening is that Foo actually runs onpageload and never onClick of link1.

What's going on?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '#link1' ).on( 'click', foo( 'hello' ) );
});

function foo( bar ){
  alert( bar );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link1">hello</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">world</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference as the click handler, you are invoking the function(By adding `()` at the end of function) so the function is executed first then the value returned by it(`undefined` in this case as the event handler.)

One solution here, since you want to pass a custom argument to the called function is to use a anonymous function as the event handler which will call `foo` with desired parameter

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#link1').on('click', function() {
    foo('hello')
  });
});

function foo(bar) {
  alert(bar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link1">hello</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">world</a>
```

---

Update if you don't want to pass any custom parameters to the target function foo then

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#link1').on('click', foo);
});

function foo(event) {
  alert('foo called');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link1">hello</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">world</a>
```

Comment: Perfect, the confusion for me was that i've been using the same format as my original post but without parameters so it's been working fine.  So would it be considered "shorthand" if I did something like $( '#link1' ).on( 'click', foo ); instead of $( '#link1' ).on( 'click', function(){foo()});?

Comment: Awesome, so i'll take that as 'yes' they are the same thing and would be considered "shorthand" if you are not passing parameters.  I still have 3 minutes to wait before I can accept your answer but I appreciate your promptness!